# How can I use Javascript/react to open iMessenger on MacOS using Chrome specifically?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sms

I am working on a site that will open up a text message button with a pre-populated body. I can get it to work just fine on with Firefox and Safari, but Chrome does literally nothing.

I am using a button with an onClick event like this:

```
<button onClick={() => {window.location = "sms:?&body=This%20is%20the%text"}>Click me</button>
```

I have also tried doing `iMessage:?&body=text` too but still nothing happens on Chrome. Firefox asks to open messages and Safari just does it. It works on iOS just fine.

EDIT: Using `iMessage` was the proper solution, but there was an issue in my code where it wasn't properly being triggered on Chrome for some reason and so `sms` was getting used, which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
    <button onClick={() => {window.location = "sms://?&body=This%20is%20the%text"}>Click me</button>
```

You were missing the double `//` before the "?"

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either.

Comment: Update: Turns out I needed to use `iMessage`, but the trigger I had for it elsewhere in my code wasn't working properly.

Comment: Ooh, weird cus it's working for me, hahaha I just opened the chrome console and ran it like `window.location = "sms://?&body=This%20is%20the%text"`

Glad that you were able to solve it!